# Jquery code is perfect for me but only works in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

So I found this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/EgCW6/)  in one of the stackoverflow forums and i can't find that forum anymore.  I am using the exact code

```
<div class="lang"> 
  <select id="language" class="selectOptionHeader">
                            <option>United Kingdom</option>
                          <option>Austria</option>
                          <option>Romania</option>
                     </select>
                </div>
<script>
                $(".lang").append("<div onclick='runThis2()' class='arrow2'></div>");

                (function () {
                    showDropdown = function (element) {
                        var event;
                        event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                        event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
                        element.dispatchEvent(event);
                    };
                    window.runThis2 = function () {
                        var dropdown = document.getElementById('language');
                        showDropdown(dropdown);
                    };
                 })();
                </script>
```

This code is perfect solution that I need.  However, it only works in chrome.  I need to get it t0 work in the other browsers, but I can't seem to find a solution.  Either there is not solution or i'm getting dumber to figure this out.

Edit:
It should also work when you click on the green box.
If there is better and another way to write please do help me. Would Really Appreciate your help.

Comment: `initMouseEvent` is deprecated. Why don't you just use jQuery's `.trigger()` method?

Comment: `showDropDown` never uses the `element` argument.

Comment: The fiddle works in Firefox.

Comment: fiddle not working in IE.

Comment: I also need to make it work when you click on the green box.  But that does not work in firefox or any other browser except chrome.

Comment: new answer tested on ie, safari and chrome all worked couldn't test on ff let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted this so the jquery was in the head and didn't load 'ondomready' and i also found that it ran cross-browser using jquery 2.02 (+) but not anything below. There are no errors. I replaced the arrow class with a radial gradient. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/tjz3buna/)

```js
$("#dropdown").click(function() {
  showDropdown = function(element) {
    var event;
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  };

  window.runThis1 = function() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    showDropdown(dropdown);
  };

  window.runThis2 = function() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown2');
    showDropdown(dropdown);
  };
});
```

```css
.drop {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    
    background-image: url(http://www.msskincarebeautysalon.com/images/downArrow.png), -webkit-radial-gradient(top left, circle, rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.3) 80%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5) 20%);
    background-image: url(http://www.msskincarebeautysalon.com/images/downArrow.png), -moz-radial-gradient(top left, circle, rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.3) 80%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5) 20%);
    background-image: url(http://www.msskincarebeautysalon.com/images/downArrow.png), -ms-radial-gradient(top left, circle, rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.3) 80%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5) 20%);
    background-image: url(http://www.msskincarebeautysalon.com/images/downArrow.png), -o-radial-gradient(80% 20%, circle, rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.3), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5));
    background-image: url(http://www.msskincarebeautysalon.com/images/downArrow.png), radial-gradient(top left, circle, rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.3) 80%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5) 20%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position: right center;

    height: auto;
    
    border-radius: 4px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #f00;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:0 10px;
    position:relative;
}
.drop select {
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #f00;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.drop option {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drop">
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="categ1">Category1</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="drop">
    <select id="dropdown2">
        <option value="categ1">Category1</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed and how you think it addresses the problem?

Comment: Chrome is reporting a syntax error from your code. I don't think you can have an unnamed function expression at top-level in JS. You never call that function -- the old code was an IIFE.

Comment: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (**

Comment: Anyway, you should put the explanation *in the answer*, not a comment.

Comment: Hi Rachel, when you click on the green box, it does not work for other browsers.

Comment: @TheFron it works when you click on the body of the element

Comment: @Rachel, when I ran the code snippet in the Firefox window, it wasn't working.  Not sure how it is working for you.  Can you put it in fiddle by if possible?

Comment: @Rachel, you did put it in fiddle but it doesn't work with the greenbox.

Comment: and the issue with chrome was just that you couldn't see a dropdown but if you change the color of the box and add a path to an image it works fine

Comment: i can't run ff on my machine, it crashes. so i can't test it in ff